# pyschools: wrong answer being given by site? (Topic 2, Q 7)

Tags: python

I am new to python! Done my studying, gone through several books and now attempting pyschools challenges. Done Variables and data types successfully but Question 7 of Topic 2 (Functions) is giving me hell.

I am using Eclipse with Python (ver 3.2). in my eclipse, I get the answers 100, 51 and 525. Those are the same answers pyschools expects but it shows that my function returns 100, 0 and 500.

Here is the question (Hope am allowed to post it here!):
Write a function percent(value, total) that takes in two numbers as arguments, and returns the percentage value as an integer.
And below is my function

```
    def percent (value, total):
        a = value
        b = total
        return(int((a / b) * 100))
    percent(70, 70)
    percent(46, 90)
    percent(63, 12)
```

Can anyone tell me what pyschools really want me to do or where am going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using Python 3.x and they're using Python 2.x. In Python 2.x, the `/` operation is always an integer division when the arguments are integers. `1/2` is `0`. So, use `float()` to change one of your arguments to a floating-point number, such as `int((float(a) / b) * 100)`. Then `a/b` will have a fractional part.

Or, assuming they are using a recent version of Python 2.x, you can just add this to the beginning of your script and it should work on the site:

```
from __future__ import division
```

As an aside, why are you assigning your input parameters to variables? They're already variables. If you want them named `a` and `b`, just receive them that way:

```
def percent(a, b):
    return int((float(a) / b) * 100)
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked: 

        return int((float(a) / b) * 100)

Answer (score 1):

because it is using python 2.x you need to atleast convert one value to float

```
def percent(number, total):
    return int((float(number)/total)  * 100)
```

this will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Python performs mathematical operations on integers with strictly integer math, truncating fractional parts.

To avoid that, multiply one of the inputs by 1.0 before dividing.

Comment: Your remarks apply only to the default behaviour of Python 2.x. Multiplying the numerator by 100.0 before dividing is a better tactic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the truncating divide, like this:

```
def percent(value, total):
    return value * 100 // total
```

Advantages:

(0) Works with all Pythons from 2.2 onwards.

(1) The reader knows what that one line does without having to guess what version of Python is being run and without having to inspect the start of the module for `from __future__` magic.

(2) Avoids any potential floating-point problems.

(3) Avoids using `float` and `int` i.e. saves two (relatively expensive) function calls.

Note carefully: `//` works on `float` objects as well as `int` objects. The question says that the args are "numbers" (can include `float` objects) and the result should be an "integer" (not necessarily an `int` object). That gives you considerable licence.

```
>>> percent(63.001, 11.9999)
525.0 # That's an integer
```

If they insist on the return value being an `int` object, then of course you'll need an `int()`.